# How to print an Output value in Anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

I am running an Optimization experiment with AnyLogic, In the proprieties --> Java Actions --> At the end of the iteration, I need to print out the results on excel.

While I am able to print out the optimal values of the resources that vary, I cannot find a way on how to print out the utilization of these resourses. The utilizations are set as OUTPUT blocks on the main.

I tried to do it as root.utilizationAB but it gives me errors. Have any idea?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You only have access to your `root` at the end of a replication (because several replications can make up 1 iteration).

**So write that code in the "after simulation run"**. This is called after each replication.

PS: Make sure you understand what replications and iterations are and that your optimization experiment is statistically sound, applying replications. All described in the help...